# SSH key based login not working

Tags: ssh, login, sshd, ssh-keygen

I am trying to setup *SSH key based login* from server A to server B.

I ran `ssh-keygen` on server A and used `ssh-copy-id` to copy the id_rsa.pub to server B.
When I try to `ssh user@serverB` from server A, I keep getting the error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have double checked my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config file` to make sure everything is setup correctly. Also have SELinux disabled on both servers. Any idea what could be causing this problem.

Comment: Check the permissions on the folder and key; check that the key is of a type that the server can accept (does it have to be an ecdsa key?); run the ssh command with -vvv and see what it says.

Comment: Try debugging the authentication by looking at `/var/log/auth.log`. If not present, you need to enable `SyslogFacility AUTH` in `sshd_config`, and maybe adjust `(r)syslogd` config accordingly.

Comment: `/var/log/auth.log` is part of Debian-style (r)syslog configuration; RedHat-related distributions might use `/var/log/secure` for the same purpose. And the logs should be checked specifically on server B.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the RSA key on the new server that I was logging in from (server A) was of a bigger size than what the old server I was logging in to (server B) could handle. I generated a ed25519 key on the new server and adding that to the authorized_keys file worked. Good reason to start moving away from RSA keys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check:

- The types of key the server B can accept
- If the ssh pubkey is applied correctly to the authorized_keys file of the user you're trying to login with the key (usually `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`)
- The permission of the private key (Needs not to be open to other users)
- The permission of the `authorized_keys` file (Same as above).
- The owner of the `authorized_keys` file (Needs to be the user).

The output would be more helpful, but for now, that's all I can think of.

Comment: Also ownership and permissions of the all the directories containing the keys, including `$HOME`, `/`, `$HOME/..` and `$HOME/.ssh` on server  B. Some systems give each user their own group and make $HOME group writable which can cause issues.